# Check the render method of `Drawer Sidebar`

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React-navigation module, and I Created `DrawerContent` and I Got this Error:
`Check the render method of "Drawer Sidebar"`
How Can I Fix this Error?
[image: photo]

**Default Code is ok:**
`contentComponent: props => <ScrollView><DrawerItems {...props} /></ScrollView>`

**My new Code is Not ok:**
`contentComponent: DrawerContent`
and
`const DrawerContent = (props) => (<ScrollView><DrawerItems {...props} /></ScrollView>)`

I opened This Issue too: (https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2175)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ✔️
`contentComponent: props => <DrawerContent {...props} />`

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this:

```
contentComponent: props => <DrawerNavigatorItems {...this.props} />
```