# Getting problems with Drawer Items - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native with React Navigation 4.0.5 and getting this error:

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `contentComponent`.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Platform, SafeAreaView, Button, View } from 'react-native';
import * as authActions from '../store/actions/auth';


const MenuNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Mapa: MapaNavigator,
    Pedidos: PedidosNavigator,
    Usuario: UsuarioNavigator
  },
  {
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: Colors.primary
    },
    contentComponent: props => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
          <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <Button
              title="Logout"
              color={Colors.primary}
              onPress={() => {
                dispatch(authActions.logout());
              }}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

If I comment `<DrawerItems {...props} />` all code works showing only the logout button... Adding `<DrawerItems {...props} />` the above error appears...

Answer (score 3):

I just found the **solution** in this [guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html)

```
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerNavigatorItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
```

Replace this

```
<DrawerItems {...props} />
```

by this

```
<DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />
```

Comment: Can you please check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605603/element-type-is-invalid-when-use-react-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `DrawerItem` with `DrawerNavigatorItems` was part of the issue for me. But for some reason I still had to export this as a separate component. Try making a separate component like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { DrawerNavigatorItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer'

const Logout = props => {
    return <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />
            <Button title="Logout" onPress={() => { }} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
};

export default Logout
```

The in the Navigator add `import Logout from '../components/Logout'` and then use `contentComponent: props => {return <Logout {...props} />;}`. It would not let me define the component inline.

Answer (score 0):

Add import

```
 import { Button, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Hello, I just forgot to copy that line in the example code..But I have already imported  those components and still getting the same error

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167415/check-the-render-method-of-drawer-sidebar/45172687#45172687

Comment: import { DrawerItems, SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';